# How to create separate tags for each for loop iteration?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm using d3 and javascript to display data from a csv file in columns on an html page. Everything works fine and dandy for one csv 
(the html output looks something like this)

```
 <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
 <h2>Column 1</h2>
 // p tags generated from csv here 
 </div>
```

for a multiple columns the html is expected to look like this:

```
<div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
<h2>Column 1</h2>
// p tags generated from csv here 
</div> 
<div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
<h2>Column 2 </h2>
// p tags generated from csv 2 here 
</div> 
<div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
<h2>Column n </h2>
// p tags generated from csv n here 
</div>
```

however, my output when trying to generate the tags in a loop is just:

```
<div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
<h2>Column n </h2>
// p tags generated from csv n here 
</div>
```

only the last csv is ever written to the dom and I'm not sure why. So far my code looks like this:

```
var i;
array = ["72.csv", "122.csv", "124.csv", "12.csv",]
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) { 

    document.getElementById("inner").innerHTML="<div class=\"column\" style=\"background-color:#aaa;\">";
    var dataPath = array[i]
    d3.csv(dataPath, function (error, data){
        var myData = data;
        var booksExtent = d3.extent(myData, function(d) {
            return parseInt(d.score)
        });
            var scale = d3.scaleLinear()
                .range([9, 20])
                .domain([12,85])
            d3.select(".column")
                .selectAll("p")
                    .data(myData)
                    .enter()
                    .append("p")
                        .text(function(d){
                        return d.word; 
                    })
                    .style("font-size", function (d)
                    {
                        return scale(parseInt(d.score)) + "pt";
                    });
        })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fundamental problem here, which is using a **for loop** with an **asynchronous function**. It simply won't work.

This is the issue:

`d3.csv` is an asynchronous function, that is, the code doesn't wait for the response (XHR if you're using D3 v4, promise if you're using D3 v5) from `d3.csv` and the rest of it keep running. Because of that, the `for` loop doesn't wait for each individual `d3.csv` to finish before going to the next iteration: in fact, the `for` loop will run to the end in a couple of milliseconds.

So, you'll have to refactor all your code.

There are several ways to fix this problem. This is a possible solution, which is not the most elegant but it's easy to understand: do 4 separate `d3.csv` calls, one for each CSV, and pass the data to the function that appends the elements:

```
d3.csv("72.csv", createElements);
d3.csv("122.csv", createElements);
d3.csv("124.csv", createElements);
d3.csv("12.csv", createElements);

var counter = 0;

function createElements(myData) {

  counter++;

  var div = d3.select("#inner")
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "column")
    .style("background-color", "#aaa");

  div.append("h1")
    .text("Column " + counter);

  var booksExtent = d3.extent(myData, function(d) {
    return parseInt(d.score)
  });

  var scale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([9, 20])
    .domain([12, 85]);

  div.selectAll(null)
    .data(myData)
    .enter()
    .append("p")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.word;
    })
    .style("font-size", function(d) {
      return scale(parseInt(d.score)) + "pt";
    });

}
```

For creating the `<h1>` you can keep an external counter, as I'm doing here, but just as an example (it's not a good approach).